# How can I create a new variable with the sum of all elements in the file with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create a new variable with the total amount of elements ingredient in the file.
So what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <pc:recipe
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        version="0.1">
    <pc:ingredient name="tomato">
    </pc:ingredient>
    <pc:ingredient name="onion">
    <pc:ingredient>
    <pc:ingredient name="paprika">
    </pc:ingredient>
   </pc:recipe>
```

So what I need to create a new variable in the XSLT-file with the total number of ingredients in the XML-file (in this example totalAmount=3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Maybe someone can help me with this.

Comment: what is the namespace for `pc`? Your example XML uses the `pc` prefix, but doesn't show what the namespace is.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply

```
<xsl:variable name="number-of-ingredients"
              select="count(//pc:ingredient)"/>
```

but you'll need to ensure that the prefix "pc" is declared in both the source document and the stylesheet.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I tried your code and have the error message: A variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect. Maybe you know how can I fix it?

Comment: The error message means that the variable has been declared but not used. The "scope" of a variable in XSLT (i.e. the portion of the stylesheet in which the variable is visible to other code) is the following siblings of the `<xsl:variable>` element, and their descendants. If the variable isn't referred to anywhere by other XPath expressions in that scope, then it has no purpose, and your `<xsl:variable>` _has_ no following siblings. An XSLT interpreter will not even attempt to evaluate the variable's `select` expression. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#scope-of-variables for details

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume this is your xml (using a namespace for pc)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pc:recipe version="0.1"
  xmlns:pc="some-url-for-pc" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <pc:ingredient name="tomato"> </pc:ingredient>
  <pc:ingredient name="onion"> </pc:ingredient>
  <pc:ingredient name="paprika"> </pc:ingredient>
</pc:recipe>
```

And this the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:pc="some-url-for-pc">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!--  The identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pc:recipe">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <!-- Insert a new element with the number-of-ingredients -->
      <pc:number-of-ingredients>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(pc:ingredient)"/>
      </pc:number-of-ingredients>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Than this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pc:recipe xmlns:pc="some-url-for-pc"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           version="0.1">
   <pc:ingredient name="tomato"> </pc:ingredient>
   <pc:ingredient name="onion"> </pc:ingredient>
   <pc:ingredient name="paprika"> </pc:ingredient>
   <pc:number-of-ingredients>3</pc:number-of-ingredients>
</pc:recipe>
```